# Unable install jdk8 in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: java

I used the following code to install jdk 8  and to add repository

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

After this when I try to install Java using the following command,

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

I am getting message, the code response is,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java8-installer is already the newest version (8u151-1~webupd8~0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1):

> oracle-java8-installer is already the newest version

That's the error message that you get when you try to install the same package twice because the package is already installed. To prove it run the following command to show whether oracle-java8-installer is installed:

```
apt policy oracle-java8-installer
```

When you tried to install oracle-java8-installer you got the following error message:

```
Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing: oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

apt says that oracle-java8-installer is installed but `java -version` can't find java, so it must not have been installed correctly due to the `sha256sum mismatch` error which means that jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz was not downloaded correctly by the oracle-java8-installer  script.

You might be having the same problem that others have that the oracle-java8-installer script isn't working properly: [when i try to install or remove any softwares itis errer will occure please anyone help me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978307/when-i-try-to-install-or-remove-any-softwares-itis-errer-will-occure-please-anyo/978322#978322) so visit the official [Oracle Java 9 website](https://www.oracle.com/java/java9.html), download jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz from there, and install it by following the instructions in this answer: [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre).

Comment: yes i cheked  your command.Now i do?

Comment: If `apt policy oracle-java8-installer` says that oracle-java8-installer is installed then you don't need to do anything. If the Candidate version of a package is newer than the Installed version then it is possible to use apt to update that package to the latest version using the command: `sudo apt upgrade oracle-java8-installer`

Comment: But when i run java  -version: The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:

Comment: [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre) and then set Java 8 as the default Java with the command: `sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to confirm its installed is running this command from your terminal:

```
 dpkg-query -l oracle-java8-installer
```

You should see this:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                               Version                Architecture           Description
+++-==================================-======================-======================-=========================================================================
ii  oracle-java8-installer             8u151-1~webupd8~0      all                    Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 8
```

The second `i` means its installed.

From `man dpkg-query`:

```
-l, --list [package-name-pattern...]
              List  packages  matching  given  pattern.  If  no package-name-pattern is given, list all packages in /var/lib/dpkg/status, excluding the ones
              marked as not-installed (i.e. those which have been previously purged). Normal shell wildcard characters are allowed in  package-name-pattern.
              Please  note  you  will  probably have to quote package-name-pattern to prevent the shell from performing filename expansion. For example this
              will list all package names starting with “libc6”:

                dpkg-query -l 'libc6*'

              The first three columns of the output show the desired action, the package status, and errors, in that order.

              Desired action:
                u = Unknown
                i = Install
                h = Hold
                r = Remove
                p = Purge

              Package status:
                n = Not-installed
                c = Config-files
                H = Half-installed
                U = Unpacked
                F = Half-configured
                W = Triggers-awaiting
                t = Triggers-pending
                i = Installed

              Error flags:
                <empty> = (none)
                R = Reinst-required

              An uppercase status or error letter indicates the package is likely to cause severe problems. Please refer to dpkg(1)  for  information  about
              the above states and flags.

              The  output  format  of this option is not configurable, but varies automatically to fit the terminal width. It is intended for human readers,
              and is not easily machine-readable. See -W (--show) and --showformat for a way to configure the output format.
```

Comment: yes i cheked your command.Now i do?

Comment: Run `java -version` if your still not sure if installed

Comment: when i run java  -version :  
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:

Comment: What happens when you do?

Comment: When i run command sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer then says Download done and Oracle jdk is not installed

Comment: DID YOU RUN `dpkg -l oracle-java8-installer` and what were the results?

Comment: Please run the commands we give and post the results into your question so we know what is good and what is not, I am a bit confused as to what your trying to achieve here.

Comment: when i run dpkg -l oracle-java8-installersame result which you mention previous question

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install --reinstall oracle-java8-installer` work? It should reinstall the package and then run the script to actually (re)download and install Oracle Java...